# Running LVM using VNC Viewer on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, lvm, vnc

Need to run Logical Volume Manager on my CentOS 6 vm (Created by VMWare) using VNC Viewer but when I double click on it, nothing happens.

What I did is to go to System > Administrator > Logical Volume Manager

Am I missing something ? Is there any other way to run LVM on a CentOS machine?

Comment: Simply open a terminal or ssh in and use the command line tools...

Comment: I don't understand some sick people who like to downvote even a helpful question. I searched all over the web before asking my question here but didn't find the answer. If a question seems silly to you it's not a good reason to downvote a question. Maybe it's a useful question for others. Be more respectful.

Comment: By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Also questions can attract a down vote when not [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681), not quite [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or missing details.

Answer (score 0):

As HBrujin said it should be run using a terminal.
I used the following command to open LVM on my CentOS machine:

```
system-config-lvm
```